# How to speed up for huge tables in SQL select query?

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

I have the following huge tables.

Table_1 with 500000 (0.5m) rows

Table_8 with 20000000 (20m) rows

Table_13 with 4000000 (4m) rows

Table_6 with 500000 (0.5m) rows

Table_15 with 200000 (0.2m) rows

I need to pull out so many records(recent events) to show on google map by joining about 28 tables.

How to speed up for huge tables in SQL select query ?

I searched from Google to use the clustered index and non clustered indexes. By getting the advices from DTA(Database Engine Tuning Advisor), I build those clustered index and non clustered indexes. But it still take long time.

I have 2 views and 1 stored procedure as the following.

https://gist.github.com/LaminGitHub/57b314b34599b2a47e65

Please kindly give me idea.

Best Regards

Comment: One word, DataWarehouse.  Maybe also just flattening out some/all of the tables.

Comment: Check the query plan before and after you implemented the DTA advice. Did the query plan change? Are the ORDER BY's in the view really necessary? Can you make database or data changes to speed this up? i.e. add a 'current row' flag to `Table_3` so you don't need to do a correlated MAX on it in View 1. What kind of latency can you handle? Your stored procedure might be suffering from 'parameter sniffing' also. How complex are scalar functions `Table_3` and `GetPagingRowIndexMin`? Can you rewrite the query so these are not required? Scalar function can cause huge performance problems

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid, I notice the logical reads of Table_7 and Table_8 are very high. It changed a bit before and after. Table_8 has 20000000 rows and Table_7 has 1147 rows. That's the main cause of the performance problem ? I added the query plan message (before and after). How can i reduce the logical read ? Please kindly advice me. Thanks.

Comment: It might be logical reads. It might be something else. This is a complex topic. By query plan I mean CTRL-L. Does anything change when adding indexes? Consider answering some of the other things in my comment also. I think this might be too complicated to easily answer in this kind of forum.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid, The query plan changed a bit. I found one thing. I ran the view1, "View1_GetList" and it didn't take too long. After that, I ran the view2, it took too long because it joined view1 and another tables.

Comment: The first step is to see if it uses the indexes you created - you can see this in the query plan. Anyway I have a whole load of comments above that you should have a think about.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid, thanks for you comments. Now I never used the scalar valued function and the correlated Max in View1. View1 is ok already. When I join the View1 and another 1 table, it takes long time.

Comment: You mention you need to show this on google maps. Why do you need to order the data? Ordering is expensive but all of your queries have it

Comment: Thanks Nick.McDermaid. I showed this on Google maps as recent evnets. Even i remove away the ordering, it still took too long. Is there a way to store a large chunk of data for future ease of access?

Comment: Did removing the ordering speed it up at all? Did you take metrics to be certain? removing the ordering might be just just one piece of performance improvement. How often does the information in the base tables change? If it changes every day at it's most frequent you could create some tables to dump it into every night. But if it changes every few minutes or so that is not an option

Comment: Thanks Nick. Now I drop the unnecessary non clustered index and used the required non clustered indexes. It reduced the logical reads and improve performance. There is one huge table,(Table_7) that their non clustered indexes are used by the views but not used by stored procedure. Would you know why like that?